# Shorthand for loop passing three times even if array lenght is 1?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript function in external .js file:

```
function init() {
 var v = document.getElementsByTagName('video'),i;
 console.log(v.length);
  for (i in v) {
console.log("class:" + v[i].className + "id:" + v[i].id);
}
}
init();
```

And one video element in dedicated html page. This is what script returns to Chrome console:

```
1     //  v.length
class:video1id:bigBunny    //first pass of for loop
class:undefinedid:undefined     //??
class:undefinedid:undefined     //??
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 8):

A `NodeList` (returned by `getElementsByTagName`) has not only the elements but two additional properties:

```
length   (the amount of elements)
item     (to get an element, basically the same as using [i] notation)
```

You're iterating them as well and treating as if they are elements. They're not; they don't have a class nor an ID. You should use a numeric `for` loop (`for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++`) instead. This (unlike `for in`) obviously can't include such properties.

Comment: Oh my bad, i thought it returns array of elements, and my code had sense, thank you very much.

Comment: @wazzup: Even an array can have properties other than only its indices. It's recommended not to use `for in` in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a traditional for loop anyway.

```
for(var i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
{
    console.log("class:" + v[i].className + "id:" + v[i].id);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately a `for in` loop does give you the keys rather than the values.

Comment: @pimvdb oh...crap, you're right. Didn't know that -- never used it before :P